# expected primary-expression before ‘int’ Attempting to call function

Tags: c++

When I call function mooreNeighbor I get error:

> expected primary-expression before ‘int’

The error happens on the line where the call is being made.

Barray is a (int)1D array of 1s and 0s. Width and height are both intgers. All three are initialised with values.

Lines 86-87 from my main.cc:

`//#include "contour-tracing.h" is included at the top of the file
    Barray = mooreNeighborTracing(int * Barray, width, height);`

From contour-tracing.h:

```
// @author Erik Smistad <smistad@idi.ntnu.no>
#ifndef CONTOURTRACING_H_
#define CONTOURTRACING_H_

#include <stdlib.h>

int * padImage(int * Barray, int width, int height,int zero);
int * mooreNeighborTracing(int * Barray, int height, int width);

#endif /* CONTOURTRACING_H_ */
```

There is another file contour-tracing.cpp where the algorithm exists. I can post info from it too.

Comment: `Barray` isn't declared anywhere.

Comment: You don't include parameter types when calling a function.

Comment: you're calling `mooreNeighborTracing` with the wrong syntax for the 1st param

Comment: (1) As @chris said, you don't include the int* (just like you didn't include `int` when you passed in width and height.) (2) You reversed the width and the height in your call to `mooreNeighborTracing`. It's width, height.. not height, width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the function the following way

```
Barray = mooreNeighborTracing(Barray, width, height);
```

I suppose that Barray is a pointer that is it is declared as

```
int *Barray /* = some initializer as for example an expression with the operator new */;
```

If Barray is defined as an array then you may not assign it. It seems that in this case the function should be called as

```
mooreNeighborTracing(Barray, width, height);
```

Comment: Okay thanks for responses so far. I changed it to what you have Vlad, and I get this error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int*’ to ‘int [(((long unsigned int)(((long int)n) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)]’

Comment: we don't know who and what `Barray` is, we can only assume it's an `int*`

Comment: @user3707614 You can create another thread relative to your new error.

Comment: These are lines 80-88:                                           `int* Barray;
Barray = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
for (q=0;q<n;q++){
if (rgbArray[q]=="(0,0,0)")
{Barray[q]=0;}
else {Barray[q]=1;}
//cout<<Barray[q];
}

Barray=mooreNeighborTracing(Barray, height, width);`